# VS2010 Debug Level Mismatch

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, static-libraries

I noticed while testing my library that VS2010 will throw an error if I try to **link to a static library built in Release mode when the project is in Debug mode.**  Inversely, it appears that the same thing happens if I try to link to a library built in Debug with a project built in Release.

`error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in Main.obj`

Is there a way to bypass this strange behavior?  Do I just have to distribute two versions of my library?  In addition, why does this happen in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a strange behavior, compiler creates different images depending on macro defines, optimization and other flags. It's better not to distribute static libraries, because the users will have to have exactly the same compiler version, standard library version, same compiler flags or you risk incompatibilities: sometimes you get linking errors, sometimes the application will crash, sometimes it will behave incorrectly.

Comment: If users of static libraries **and** dynamic libraries have to compile their code under the same versions and settings as the libraries were built under, how are libraries distributed?

Answer (score 1):

Library writers don't have great options to point out that mixing and matching does not work.  They have to trigger linker errors, always tricky and confuzzling.  What doesn't work here is that you cannot mix a library that uses the STL classes with iterator debugging enabled with code that has it disabled.  Pretty fundamental mismatch, those template class objects are not the same size.  If you really want to do this then you'll have to disable the diagnostics you get from the feature.

That requires building the debug version of your code with the _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING macro #defined to 0.  Are you sure you want to do this?